# SQLite Data retrieval to one Class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So, as you can see by my screenshot below I have six buttons: e.g. B1,B2.
when I click on a certain button say B1, I have written a function that gets the row of data from my SQLite DB and it uses the B1 as the primary key to do this. I have a java class and an activity that then displays the information from the database separately in different textviews. All is working fine for the data retrieval of B1.

My question is: Due to the fact that I only have one activity to display the data and the data retrieved depends on what button they choose (B1,B2 etc.) how can I determine which data retrieval function is correctly used corresponding to which button they press?

Data retrieval function code:

```
public Cursor getProgressBar1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"B1"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar2() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"B2"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar3() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"B3"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar4() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S1"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar5() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S2"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar6() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S3"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}
```

Code on the Details class to display the right data in TextViews:

```
 SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
Cursor res;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verify_line);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

    res = myDb.getProgressBar1();

    TextView LT = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewspinner1);
    TextView PT = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewspinner2);
    TextView QTY = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
    TextView DUR = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
    TextView ST = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewStartTime);
    TextView ET = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewendtime);


    if (res.moveToFirst()) {
        LT.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("LINETYPE")));
        PT.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("PACKAGETYPE")));
        QTY.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("QUANTITY")));
        DUR.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("DURATION")));
        ST.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("STARTTIME")));
        ET.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ENDTIME")));
```

> SO FOR EXAMPLE HERE.. I WANT IT SO THAT IF THEY CLICK ON B2 THEN I
>   WOULD HAVE
>
> res = myDb.getProgressBar2(); THEN ALL THE TEXTVIEWS SET TO THE B2 DATA

Here is a screenshot to show you what I mean by clicking b1 or b2:

[image: ButtonClickscreen]

Answer (score 0):

You should use only one function and pass it button id such as "B1" for button1.
and call this function on button's click and do rest of work in button's click listener.

on your button say B1's click, call function
getProgressBar("B1");

and your function will be

public Cursor getProgressBar(String buttonId) 
{

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

```
Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{buttonId},null,null,null);
return res;
```

}

Comment: the B1,B2 etc is not the button. it is the primary key in the Database and that is how I am retrieving each row.

Comment: does not matter, you can still do it this way. you can pass your desired key as string in function.

Comment: another thing is.. I am not retrieving the data to the same activity. so I am clicking the button on one activity and I want it to display the data on the next activity that is opened